# To know the type of widget in horizontal panel in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT project. I am using a `getWidget()` method on a horizontal panel and I want to know the type of widget returned by this method.
 Whether the returned widget is a button or a textbox (as I would have put only these 2 kinds of widget into my horizontal panel initially).

For example:

```
HorizontalPanel x;
X.getWidget(4);
```

I want to know the type of the widget returned.

Is there any method for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the returned widget with `instanceof`

Example:

```
final Widget widget = horizontalPanel.getWidget(0);
if (widget instanceof Button) {
    System.out.println("It's a button!");
} else if (widget instanceof TextBox) {
    System.out.println("It's a textbox!");
}
```